# Refresh div content without reload page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having some trubles when update the div content without reload the page. I'm using jquery, php and mysql as well. Well I've tryed:

```
$('#divId').load("script.php", function(){
   someFunction();
});
```

But it's not working at all :(
I apreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Are you getting any script errors?

Comment: Should be $('#divId').load() instead of $.('#divId').load() ?

Comment: Your code is invalid `$.('#divID')` should be `$('#divID')`

Comment: well I believe so, I have a folder at the root of the server where the script.php is located so I believe that the path toscritp.php is ...'/folder/scrit.php', function(){ ... });

Comment: I have corrected $('#divID') but that is not the problem.. still not working

Comment: Please show more code, like the div you would like to refresh as well as some content around the jquery also make sure there is a `;` at the end of your jquery

Comment: Yes I have placed ; at the end of the jquery code... I will update the initial code, thank you.

Comment: Define "not working".  Are you getting any Javascript errors?  Can you verify in Firebug's console that the Ajax request is not firing?  Is the Ajax request completing, but `someFunction()` is not getting invoked?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$.('#divId').load("script.php", function(){
   someFunction();
})
```

To:

```
$('#divId').load('script.php', function(){
   someFunction();
});
```

Comment: the php script it's working because it's called at the beginning of the  page and generates the div content ok...

Comment: Thank's Michael Robinson I've solved the all puzzle load doesn't work properly I've replaced by : $("#leftDiv").load(location.href+" #leftDiv>*", function(){ ... now I'm dealing with some minor troubles with the button but it's working! ;)